# Генерация произвольного количества интервалов if else в Verilog-2001

Tags: generate, verilog

Нужно  проверить в какой из интервалов попадает значение sum и в зависимости от этого интервала вычислить значение mod.

Должно получится что-то вроде:

```
        generate
        for (i=0; i<COEFF_SUM_MAX/MOD_VALUE; i=i+1) begin: gen_mod_out
                always @ (posedge clk) if ( ( sum>=j*MOD_VALUE ) && ( sum<(( j+1 )*MOD_VALUE )) ) mod <= sum - j*MOD_VALUE; //          
           end
        endgenerate
```

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: В смысле, за вас код написать надо?

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Интересен сам синтаксис, потому как приведённый выше не работает. И вообще возможно ли сделать это в Verilog-2001?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно работало что-то вроде такого, но лучше использовать SystemVerilog. RTL код почти такой же, но синтезатор более понятливый.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    generate for (j = 0; j < COEFF_SUM_MAX / MOD_VALUE; j = j + 1)
        begin: gen
            if (sum >= j * MOD_VALUE && sum < (j + 1) * MOD_VALUE)
                mod <= sum - j * MOD_VALUE;
        end
    endgenerate
end
```

Если generate сложно написать, то можно написать функцию

```
always @(posedge clk)
    mod <= my_func(sum);

function [31:0] my_func(input [31:0] sum);
    integer j;
    reg fin;

    begin
        my_func = 32'h0;
        fin = 1'b0;

        for (j = 0; j < COEFF_SUM_MAX / MOD_VALUE; j = j + 1)
            if (!fin && sum >= j * MOD_VALUE && sum < (j + 1) * MOD_VALUE)
                begin
                    my_func = sum - j * MOD_VALUE;
                    fin = 1'b1;
                end
    end
endfunction
```